# How to set tab delimiter using psql -F

Tags: postgresql

I want to dump a select query to a tab-delimited text file using psql -F. However, this doesn't work:

```
psql -Umyuser mydb -F '\t' --no-align -c "select * from mytable" -o /tmp/dumpfile.txt
```

That makes the delimiter a literal \t. How do I get it to use real tabs instead?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think you just need to use a literal tab.  How this works depends on your shell.  Have you seen this [post](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2006-11/msg00163.php)?

In the bash shell you can do this with `$'\t'`.

Using the example in your question:

```sh
psql -Umyuser mydb -AF $'\t' --no-align -c "select * from mytable" -o /tmp/dumpfile.txt
```

From `man bash`:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI  C standard. [...] The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar  sign had not been present.

Comment: Thanks! That thread helped. I got it to work using `psql -Umyuser mydb -F $'\t' --no-align -c "select * from mytable" -o /tmp/dumpfile.txt`

Comment: the comment from Jammie Forrest is very useful. fbarber perhaps could add it to the answer

Comment: I had to add `-A` as well, to force unaligned output. This may have become a requirement in more recent psql versions.

Answer (score 10):

In Unix, you can also type

```
ctrl-V tab
```

ctrl-V tells the terminal not to interpret the next key.

This also works with carriage returns (^M) and many other special keys like arrow keys

Answer (score 9):

In case if somebody looked for how to do it in the interactive shell:
`\f '\t'`

Comment: FWIW the output here pastes into Google Sheets nicely ;-)

Comment: See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html: `This is equivalent to \pset fieldsep`. I also had to set unaligned mode: `\pset format unaligned`